# Passing pointers to vector1 from vector2 and clearing vector1 safe?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm still kind of new to C++ and this is probably an easy answer but I have a situation where I have a vector holding some pointers to objects and I give those pointers to another vector. Does clearing the second vector cause trouble like orphaning or memory leaks?

Edit:
I guess I wasn't clear, here's an example

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<SomeObject*> objects1; # Assume this is filled with objects
std::vector<SomeObject*> objects2; # Empty

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects1.size(); i++)
{
    objects2.push_back(objects1[i]);
}
# There's some code in between, the objects themselves aren't modified
# it's just organization
objects2.clear(); # The question is about this line here
```

Comment: moving : no , deleting : yes

Comment: Clearing a vector doesn't delete any pointers stored inside, if this is your doubt.

Comment: Since you are new to C++, I am assuming you are using plain pointers. In this case you wont have any problem

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Clearing can delete if the pointers are unique or shared (if count reaches 0)

Comment: @knightrider I was talking about raw pointers of course!

Comment: What kind of pointers are you talking about: unique, shared, raw, or something else? Also what do you mean by "giving": copying or moving? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @zenith Forgot to mention I added code

Comment: Okay so you were talking about raw pointers and copying. My current answer should answer that. Destroying raw pointers doesn't destroy what they point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pointers you're talking about are raw pointers, then no. Destroying raw pointers doesn't do *anything* to what they point to.

(Unless it's the last pointer pointing to a dynamically allocated chuck of memory, in which case you're leaking that memory.)

First you have one set of pointers pointing to things, then you have another set of pointers pointing to the same things (i.e. the pointers are the same). Then you get rid of the second set of pointers.

It could more easily be written as:

```
objects2 = objects1;
```

which does exactly the same as your member-by-member copying.

---

If those pointers have the semantics of `std::unique_ptr`, then, well you can't copy them to the other vector. If by "giving" you mean "moving" then yes clearing the second vector release the memory those pointers point to.

---

If those pointers have the semantics of `std::shared_ptr`, then by giving them to the other vector you're just incrementing the reference count, and provided the original pointers in your first vector didn't go anywhere, clearing the second vector will just decrement the reference counts back to what is was before.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip. I'll remember this info for later projects